# Can't run docker containers on remote host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my php website with nginx server as docker containers on a remote server via ssh connection using docker compose

I used this command`docker-compose -H ssh://<username>@<**.***.**.***> up -d`

and got this error

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
[+] Building 8.0s (2/2) FINISHED
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                         5.0s 
 => CANCELED [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                         5.0s 
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
failed to dial gRPC: command [ssh -l username-- **.***.**.*** docker system dial-stdio] has exited with exit status 1, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    vim \
    unzip

WORKDIR /var/www
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: programwithgio-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    container_name: programwithgio-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: Do you have docker installed on the remote host with required version ? (>18.09)

Comment: Agree with @Lk77. Check the docker version.

Comment: Yes I have docker v 20.10.17 and docker compose v 2.12.0 on server